# How to load a local audio file into Wavesurfer.js?(feat Vue.js)

Tags: vue.js, wavesurfer.js

I want to load local mp3 file.
my project create vue cli
I can see wave tag in my browser but not disply mp3 file.

**my project directory**

[enter image description here][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2zizN.png

**code**

```js
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div id="waveform"></div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import WaveSurfer from 'wavesurfer.js';

export default {
  name: 'App',
  data() {
    return {
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    this.$nextTick(() => {
      this.wavesurfer = WaveSurfer.create({
          container: '#waveform',
          waveColor: 'violet',
          progressColor: 'purple'
      })
      this.wavesurfer.load('@/mp3/sample.mp3');
    })
  },
}
</script>

<style></style>
```

**package.json**

```js
"dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "wavesurfer.js": "^4.6.0"
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use refs:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div ref="waveform"></div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import WaveSurfer from 'wavesurfer.js'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  data () {
    return {
      wavesurfer: null
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    this.wavesurfer = WaveSurfer.create({
      container: this.$refs.waveform,
      waveColor: 'violet',
      progressColor: 'purple'
    })
    this.wavesurfer.load('@/mp3/sample.mp3')
  },
}
</script>
```